# Is there a way to assign true or false to contenteditable attribute conditionally?

Tags: html, angularjs-directive, contenteditable

I have a table which I want to be an editable one, I don't want all of the tows to be editable, based on a certain conditions some of them are editable and some are not. Is there a way to assign contenteditable with a conditional statement to be true or false? 
The conditions is simple, the data displayed in the table, each row of that data will have a metadata attached to it whether it is editable or not i.e. True or False.

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can. i made a simple example ( as i don't know what condition you want )

see snippet below

```js
var row = $("table tr")
$(row).each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("editMe")) {
    $(this).attr("contenteditable", true)
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="editMe">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What would the angular analogy for the same?

Comment: oh sorry. i didn't pay attention to your tags . i do not know angularJs but anyway you should specify what condition/conditions you want to be met . so it's easier to get an answer